# Xcode проблема с кнопкой

Tags: xcode, swift, button

Имеется 2 ViewController`а. Не могу перетянуть кнопку на собственноручно созданный ViewController.swift, чтобы дальше с ней работать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убедитесь, что в Storyboard Вы указали именно этот, собственноручно созданный класс контроллеру с которого action/outlet тянете.

Comment: Да, верно, не указал.
Вообще, если честно, не знал, что это нужно сделать. 
Спасибо большое.

Может заодно посоветуете какие-нибудь ресурсы на русском языке по разработке на iOS?

Comment: https://new.vk.com/iosdevcourse - группа, https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChR0_wfiEHRy9TQIN51H-OA - лучшие уроки что видел

Comment: Еще раз спасибо!